# I try to use ATR band and "valuewhen" function to set stoploss for my strategy but it is not working properly

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

First I will explain what I want the code to do:
1.I draw a ATR band(with upline and bottomline) as per my own definition.
2.Suppose when one bar is complete and it triggers the longcondition(2 EMA crossover). Let's call this bar as "bar 1".
3.Then the code will open a position at the open price of next bar(let's call it "bar 2").
4.At bar 2, I want to save the value of the upline and bottomline as a static number which don't keep updaing as the bars going on.
5.In strategy.exit I use above mentioned statisc numbers as the stoploss and takeprofit.
My codes are as below:

```
//@version=5
strategy("strategy learning", overlay=true, initial_capital=10000000)

//Draw 2 EMA lines.
ema1 = ta.ema(close, 10)
ema2 = ta.ema(close, 90)
plot(ema1, color=color.yellow)
plot(ema2, color=color.blue)

//Define a ATR band upline and bottome line.
atr = ta.atr(14)
upline = open + atr[1]
bottomline = open - atr[1]

plot(upline, color=color.white)
plot(bottomline, color=color.white)

//use "valuewhen()" function to grab the upline value and bottomline value at the moment of longcondition. It will be used for stoploss and takeprofit.
longcondition = ta.crossover(ema1, ema2)
longlimit = ta.valuewhen(longcondition, upline, 1)
longstop = ta.valuewhen(longcondition, bottomline, 1)

if(longcondition) 
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, qty=1)
strategy.exit("buy", limit=longlimit, stop=longstop)


//use "valuewhen()" function to grab the upline value and bottomline value at the moment of shortcondition. It will be used for stoploss and takeprofit. 
shortcondition = ta.crossunder(ema1, ema2)
shortlimit = ta.valuewhen(shortcondition, bottomline, 1)
shortstop = ta.valuewhen(shortcondition, upline, 1)

if(shortcondition)
    strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short, qty=1)
strategy.exit("sell", limit=shortlimit, stop=shortstop)
```

**Question1:** Please help check my codes are correct or not? Does it match with my demand?
**Question2:** I check the backtesting orders list carfully and found that many orders are not closed at the expected price as I described in the begaining of this post(sorry my reputation is not enough to add a image here). I asked similar question and others said maybe it is due to slippage which I still not able to verify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you with your first question, I think. When I load your code your take-profit and stop-loss orders aren't firing at the ATR bands. If you change the last argument of your `ta.valuewhen()` functions from 1 to 0, that fixes the issue. If they're at 1 then they fetch the value for the occurence before last of your condition - in this case, not the last ema cross, but the one before that. Zero fetches the value for the last ema cross.

I also added some plots for your take profit and stop loss lines so I could check what was going on, added `strategy.position_size == 0` to `longcondition` and `shortcondition` (so you only have one order open at a time), and indented your exit orders so they're placed at the same time as your entry orders.

So instead of:

```
 if(shortcondition) and strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short, qty=1)
         strategy.exit("exit", from_entry="sell", limit=shortlimit, stop=shortstop)
```

you have this:

```
if(shortcondition) and strategy.position_size == 0
   strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short, qty=1)
   strategy.exit("exit", from_entry="sell", limit=shortlimit, stop=shortstop)
```

All the lines you want to treat as consequences of the same if statement should be indented beneath it.

```
//@version=5
strategy("strategy learning", overlay=true, initial_capital=10000000)

//Draw 2 EMA lines.
ema1 = ta.ema(close, 10)
ema2 = ta.ema(close, 90)
plot(ema1, color=color.yellow)
plot(ema2, color=color.blue)

//Define a ATR band upline and bottome line.
atr = ta.atr(14)
upline = open + atr[1]
bottomline = open - atr[1]

plot(upline, color=color.white)
plot(bottomline, color=color.white)

//use "valuewhen()" function to grab the upline value and bottomline value at the moment of longcondition. It will be used for stoploss and takeprofit.
longcondition = ta.crossover(ema1, ema2)
longlimit = ta.valuewhen(longcondition, upline, 0)
longstop = ta.valuewhen(longcondition, bottomline, 0)

if(longcondition) and strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, qty=1)
    strategy.exit("exit", from_entry="buy", limit=longlimit, stop=longstop)

//use "valuewhen()" function to grab the upline value and bottomline value at the moment of shortcondition. It will be used for stoploss and takeprofit. 
shortcondition = ta.crossunder(ema1, ema2)
shortlimit = ta.valuewhen(shortcondition, bottomline, 0)
shortstop = ta.valuewhen(shortcondition, upline, 0)

if(shortcondition) and strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short, qty=1)
    strategy.exit("exit", from_entry="sell", limit=shortlimit, stop=shortstop)

//Plot SL and TP
    
longs = strategy.position_size > 0
shorts = strategy.position_size < 0

plot(shorts ? shortstop : na, color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(shorts ? shortlimit : na, color = color.orange, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(longs ? longstop : na, color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(longs ? longlimit : na, color = color.orange, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: @e2e4 posted while I was writing this - I defintely defer to them on this issue (I'm probably as new to Pinescript as you!)

Comment: Hello Dear Matt: thank you so much for your kindly answering. I run your codes and found it well. Really nice. I got many gains from you. 1. Now I understand how to use the "valuewhen()" function(the difference of 0 and 1,haha  O(∩_∩)O)。 2. WIth the help of your drawing the stoploss and take profit lines, I seem understand how to set statics stoploss and take profit which is really needed by me and I guess it is needed by many other people also(Since I am not a professional programmer, maybe I am not that much clear the  but I think I at leadt can use it correctly.).

Comment: Great stuff! And you introduced me to the valuewhen() function - I'll definetly be making use of it myself!

Comment: I also newly got to know this valuewhen function when I searched similiar questions in stackoverflow and saw someone suggest use it. And then I try it by myself and then face some issue so I post here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute an exit order from the local scope(this way the values won't be updated on every bar) once the entry is triggered on the previous candle (bar1):

```
if(longcondition) 
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, qty=1)

if nz(longcondition[1])
    strategy.exit("exitBuy", "buy", limit=upline, stop=bottomline)
```

[image]

If you also want to plot the correct values or use them later in the script, initialize the variables once per runtime using the **var** keyword and re-assign their values under the same entry condition. The script example below demonstrates the technique for long-side only:

```
//@version=5
strategy("strategy learning", overlay=true, initial_capital=10000000)

//Draw 2 EMA lines.
ema1 = ta.ema(close, 10)
ema2 = ta.ema(close, 90)
plot(ema1, color=color.yellow)
plot(ema2, color=color.blue)

//Define a ATR band upline and bottome line.
atr = ta.atr(14)
upline = open + atr[1]
bottomline = open - atr[1]

plot(upline, color=color.white)
plot(bottomline, color=color.white)

longcondition = ta.crossover(ema1, ema2)

if(longcondition) 
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, qty=1)

var float fixedUpline = 0
var float fixedBottonline = 0

if nz(longcondition[1])
    fixedUpline := upline
    fixedBottonline := bottomline
    strategy.exit("exitBuy", "buy", limit=fixedUpline, stop=fixedBottonline)

plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? fixedUpline : na, color = color.green, style = plot.style_linebr)
plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? fixedBottonline : na, color = color.red, style = plot.style_linebr)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your patient answer here. I run your code in tradingview and found it is working exactly as what I want.  But right now I don't quite understand the using of "var" and ":="（I didn't find this operator in PINE User Manual）and "nz". I will plot some simple lines with these three functions and try to understand them.

Comment: := is a re-assignment operator. https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#reassignement-operator

Comment: nz() function replaces the NA values from a series with zeros - https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_nz

Comment: Thank you. The idea of drawing the line segments of stoploss and take profit is great for me. But one more doubt: you use "position_size> or <0" to help u draw the line segments. But suppose now you open a bullish position(Qty=1), then u open a bearlish position(Qty=1) before last bullish position close. Now position size is 0 so the line segment will end. But maybe we want it ends at the moment of position closing. What should we do for this? (this is not a big issue because your line segments is already good enough, I just propose this doubt for discussion if you are comfortable...)